# Distinct for only one value in one column MySQL

Tags: mysql, distinct

| **Policy** | **Stat** |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | PASSED |
| P1 | FAILED |
| P2 | FAILED |
| P3 | PASSED |
| P4 | PASSED |
| P4 | FAILED |

This is the example of contents in the table. I wanted to see only which policy is failing every time it runs.

I've tried group by but it is bringing the policy even it fails one time. But I wanted to see the policy which stat is only FAILED all the time.

The result I'm expecting is...

[image]

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: Please edit your question, and share your simple data as text instead of images, so it can be easy for us to reproduce your problem

Comment: Have a look at this :: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bXbi66eGESypDscBmdnSU5/2